# Finding all integer $n$ so that period of $\cos( n x)\sin(5x/n)$ is $3\pi$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I want to find all integer $n$ so that the function has period $3\pi$. I am unable to take a start, as there is no general rule for periid of product of periodic functions. Please give a starting.

Comment: Try to express the product as a sum of trigonometric functions.

Comment: 3) things. 1) If f has period of k and g has period of m, then f.g will have period lcm (k,m).  2) if f (x) has period k, then f (nx) will have period of k/n.  3) cos and sin have period of 2 pi.  Yhose 3 things should tell you exactly how to solve this.

Comment: This is pretty old question which I forgot about eventually. I'd like to have some detailed answer to this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\cos(nx)\sin(\frac{5x}{n})$.

Note that $f(0)=0$ and $f(3\pi)=(-1)^{n}\sin(\frac{15\pi}{n})$. So if $f$ is
$3\pi$-periodic, we must have $\sin(\frac{15\pi}{n})=0$, and $n$ must divide $15$.

Conversely, suppose that $n$ divides $15$. Then $d=\frac{15}{n}$ is an odd integer. We deduce that $f(x)=\cos(nx)\sin(\frac{dx}{3})$. From $\cos(n(x+3\pi))=-\cos(nx)$ and
$\sin(\frac{d(x+3\pi)}{3})=-\sin(\frac{dx}{3})$ it follows that $f$ is $3\pi$-periodic. Done.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. It's assumed that if T is period then 2T is also called a period. For example, if n=15/3=5, then the period will be $T=\pi$.

Comment: @Mohkam7 It is indeed true that if $T$ is a period, so is $2T$ or any multiple of $T$ : the periods form a group under addition. When $n=5$, $T=\pi$ is the smallest period, and $3\pi$ is a period also.